# Why is the midpoint of a right angled triangle side always on the same height?

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

it's been a great while since I've had basic geometry, and this seems to be elude me. Here are two images of a triangle $DMC$:[image][image]
How can I prove that the midpoint of $DC$ (point $E$) will always be in the same height (the pink line) and that this height is exactly half the length of $MC$? I've tried using some triangle similarities but I was somehow unable to prove this universally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel red and green lines create similar triangles. There's no need for the triangles to be right triangles.

Comment: My confusion lies in the fact that the only similarities between the two triangles I presented are
1.) the right angle at $M$
2.) the length of $MC$.

I see that they are similar, I just need to prove it rigorously

Comment: The parallel lines create equal angles at $E$ and $D$.